# Dell XPS 15 (Dual boot) won't shut down

Tags: dual-boot, dell, shutdown, xps

I have a Dell XPS 15, set up to dual boot with windows and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

When I try to turn the machine off from Ubuntu:

[image]

it hangs indefinitely here:

[image]

and I have to manually kill it by holding the power switch down.

I have tried the suggestion here:

[Ubuntu 16 won't shut down and freezes.](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/692ifx/ubuntu_16_wont_shut_down_and_freezes/)

But no dice.

Any bright ideas as to what to do would be appreciated!

Incidentally, shutting down from windows is fine.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I recently have had a lot of grief with exactly the same problem (although not dual-booting, so I don't think that's related at all.  Here was the fix for me after doing a lot of reading and about four frustrating re-installs of Ubuntu 16.04:

1. Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.  This is required for 3rd party driver support.
2. Install NVIDIA 381 drivers following instructions here: http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/how-to-install-latest-nvidia-drivers-in-linux.  Make sure you install 381 as it will also work with suspend.
3. Reboot a few times to make sure it's fixed the issue (the first time you may have to force it).

Now the problem was fixed for me, but was using the Nvidia GPU which chews battery.  There are a few more steps if you want to use the Intel GPU and save battery.

4. Edit grub file following instructions here (answer by bt1111): [Ubuntu gnome 17.04 freezes on shutdown](https://askubuntu.com/questions/925128/ubuntu-gnome-17-04-freezes-on-shutdown)
5. Go into NVIDIA X-server settings and change to use Intel GPU - will require a log out to confirm - for me it crashed on log out but after one more foreced shut down works perfectly